# Mass of ice block needed to cool area

Tags: thermodynamics, ice

I intend to grow king oyster mushrooms inside a small greenhouse tent. The problem is the mushrooms prefer a temperature of approximately 60F. I'm trying to avoid needing to run an air conditioner to do this.

This is the tent
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0769FYDRX/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0769FYDRX)

Assume the room the tent is in will be kept about 72F. The tent is 27" x 19" x 63". Assuming the required ice would fit in the tent, I'd like to keep a few containers of that size full of ice in a freezer and swap them out when necessary, preferably once or twice a day. The ice would be on the top rack (I imagine that would be the best spot as the cold air would fall) and probably need to sit on a tray to collect condensation.

What mass of ice would I need, inside a (presumably plastic) container on a tray, to keep this tent 12F cooler? If I'm missing any necessary information, I'll update my question, or you can make assumptions based on common household conditions

Answer (score 1):

You would need to know the thermal resistance of your container, in terms of thermal conduction through the walls, radiation from light penetrating the walls (probably not a significant factor, unless in direct sunlight), and convection from the flow of air into and out of your container. None of these can be simply determined from your description, or by calculation even with detailed design drawings and material specifications. Air flow in particular is difficult to model. It would be far more effective to build it and measure the answer experimentally.

However, this way of analysing it establishes what you need to think about, which is *thermally insulating* your containers, and reducing airflow. Rather than a plastic tent, you might like to consider stacking insulated cold boxes. Use expanded polystyrene walls or wrap with blankets, divide into small spaces with solid barriers, and fill empty spaces with fibrous insulation, like cotton wool. The thicker the insulation, the less heat will leak in, and so the less heat you will need to remove with melting ice (or even just big containers full of cold water, ideally made of metal for good thermal transfer). Then use a thermometer to monitor the temperature, and adjust accordingly.

Fortunately, mushrooms don't need light to grow, but I expect they do need oxygen, and you probably need to avoid too much condensation that could encourage the wrong sort of mould to grow. So you will probably have to ensure at least *some* air circulation. But from the point of view of pure temperature management, and just using household equipment, I'd be thinking of experimenting with a big stack of insulated cold boxes, packed with cloth or cotton wool, surrounded by buckets or jerry cans of cold water (that you can swap out and put in the refrigerator), and the whole lot wrapped in blankets. Start with the minimum, and build up until you get the heat flow slow enough to satisfy you.

Another cooling method you might like to think about is evaporation. Point fans at cloth soaked in water, and the cooling effect can be dramatic. But that does raise humidity dramatically (not a good thing indoors), and I wouldn't think you would need anything that elaborate just to take 10 F off.

If you go for the 'walls of water' solution indoors, do keep an eye on the total weight, though. Water is heavy!

Comment: Thank you, I think that evaporation idea might be the easiest to implement, so I'll experiment. Maybe having the exhaust fan at a duct at the top, making negative pressure to pull in air from the bottom, and laying cold soaked cloth on a tray at the bottom could make a difference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).